# ConsumeKafka to PublishKafka doesn't keep the order of the messages in the destination topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I'm using NIFI to replicate 250 million messages between Kafka topics.

The problem is that  NIFI replicates messages in a non-sequential order, resulting in the destination topic storing messages differently than the source topic.

for example     
**source topic** - partition 0     
offset:5 key:a value:v1 
offset:6 key:a value:v2 
offset:7 key:a value:v3

**destination topic** - partition 0 
offset:5 key:a value:v2 
offset:6 key:a value:v1 
offset:7 key:a value:v3

The topics are configured with a cleanup policy: `compact`.

I'm using `ConsumeKafka` and `PublishKafka` processors to replicate topics.

[image: ConsumeKafka]
[image: ConsumeKafka2]
[image: PublishKafka]
[image: PublishKafka2]
[image: queue]

Comment: There are two options that you could try if the sequential ordering is really important for the downstream processing of your jobs, set `Partitioner class` to `RoundRobin` under the `PublishKafka`. Also to help more with the right ordering you can poll in 1 record at a time this can be set using the `Max Poll Records` under `ConsumeKafka` processor.

Comment: @DataWrangler The problem of misordering occurs within the partition. How can the use of `RoundRobin` assist in addressing the ordering issues within the partition?

Comment: Thanks, @DataWrangler I will try your suggestion using `Max Poll Records` with 1 record ,I have 250 million records so God Help Me .

Answer (score 0):

Upon examination, implementing the queue as a **First In First Out prioritizer** and configuring the load balancing strategy to **Partition by attribute** with the **kafka.partition** attribute has proven effective in maintaining the order.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khFcv.png)